# Suggestions for email providers that allow mailbox creation via API and Forwarding Rules

Tags: email

I have a web application that utilizes several CRM types of emails for notifications, appointment reminders, attachments for digital sales and such.  My clients can use my own admin domain email account to send these emails (no-reply email), or they can provide credentials for using their own SMTP server or relay service so that any emails that are replied to are sent to them (vs a no-reply admin email).

However, I'd like to try for a 3rd option where I can create an email mailbox on my a domain like so:
client1@mydomain.com
client2@mydomain.com
...

And then I would apply a forwarding rule on each one to send any replies to their personal email accounts so they wouldn't have to have their own SMTP service.

Now I can do this using providers' interfaces, but I'd rather do it with an API so I'm not having to manually create mailboxes and setting forwarding rules.

Currently I'm using AWS SES for my domain emailing, but I've searched for hours and the "solution" to create mailboxes and create rules to forward are ridiculous.

Are there any other email providers out there that make this easier?  I don't need anything fancy except the ability to create a bunch of email mailboxes via API (preferably with a high limit of mailboxes) and the ability to create the forwarding rules via API.

Or can anyone recommend a good email provider that allows for a lot of mailboxes and makes forwarding really easy (and of course cheap).

Like "cringe" GoDaddy Email or something similar??

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, this procedure doesn't really make sense these days.  There are a lot of relay email providers that make it easy to set up "Senders" so that emails can appear to come from any kind of email account (personal or domain based) for ease of use with applications